# HTML elements selectively adopting rules from stylesheet

Tags: html, css, netbeans, stylesheet

I have a stylesheet I've been building that's roughly 100 rules with about 500 declarations total. When I add another rule it isn't applied - if I open up the developer tools in Chrome when testing the page the element has no styles listed. All other rules up to this point work fine with no apparent syntax errors within the stylesheet.

Speaking of which, I use NetBeans which shows no indication of errors and finds the rules just fine as normal. To avoid the possibility of spelling errors I let NetBeans find the rule and auto-fill it.

Research into limits suggest that I am well within the boundaries of any limit but I created a new stylesheet just to test. I added a rule with all the necessary declarations I tried before and the new stylesheet worked. This was along with the original stylesheet. However, if I add another rule it wouldn't work. Only the original rule I added will work, any other additional rule will not work including if I remove the original rule entirely.

Any inline styles I create work just fine and any modifications to previous rules take affect. I don't have any idea where to go from here as the issue doesn't seem to happen with any kind of consistency. Does anybody have any suggestions?

---

**EDIT**

I made an interesting discovery. My way of importing CSS is as such for all pages:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./primary.css">
```

I tried @import with same malfunctioning results. **However**, if I include the file via PHP all rules work as expected:

```
<?php require_once('./primary.css'); ?>
```

Is there any possible explanation for this? The main difference is that now all the rules are on-page rather in a file, meaning the problem is in how the file is handled.

---

**EDIT 2**

Following suggestions from FelipeAls I began mass-commenting large portions of code to find problem areas. New rules worked when others were commented out; *however*, as I slowly re-introduced code there was no such problem area and once all code was available the problem no longer existed. This has lead me to believe there could have been a rogue comment someplace, a possible error with white space, or a line return. Either way the code works as it is supposed to once more.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does it [validate](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)? (or does each "error"/warning make sense to you?)
2. Same for HTML code, just in case
3. What if you add a test rule like `body { background-color: pink !important }` at the end of you stylesheet? Now near the *beginning* of your stylesheet?
4. Change some text in your page. Can you see the modification or do you have some proxy?
5. Remove the second half of your CSS rules. Can you now add new rules after and before the remaining first half and see their effect? No? Then remove the first half of your rules and repeat the test. Repeat with half of half etc till something works (dichotomy)
6. Rename your stylesheet to `cacheorproxyfromhell.css?v=130702-0634` and try to style your page with this one. Does your dev tool (Firebug and like) show that a different CSS is loaded? Does a modification now work?

I once forgot a closing `)` to a `url(` and it rendered void ALL rules (dozens of line of CSS) till the next closing `)`... Took me a while to figure it out while I was modifying this part!
edit: Limits? Nope. IE8 has an attainable limit of 31 stylesheets and approx. 8192 rules but don't bother for now

Comment: I've been going through my code & eliminated some things I thought were problems (modifications I've recently made) but I haven't thought of eliminating large portions to discover issues. I'll give that a go and see where I get with that. My edit probably suggests then that the PHP include means the problem is ignored rather breaking the rest of the code. Thanks!